# Обнаружение классов с поддомена php

Tags: php, namespace

Данные:

Есть домен site.com соответственно все файлы проекта лежат в корневой директории site.com. Все классы проекта загружаются через функцию autoload в файле index.php

```
private function autoload() {

    set_include_path(get_include_path());
    spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
    spl_autoload_register();

}
```

Я решил один из разделов сайта вынести на поддомен sub.site.com и подключится к основному домену с  помощью записи `require_once '../site.com/index.php';`

Проблема:

Заключается в том что поддомен не понимает пространство имен и при создании экземпляра класса выдает соответствующую ошибку. К примеру `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'engine\package' not found`

Можно ли как то решить данную проблему?

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Задача в обучении и такое условие?

Для реального проекта все же стоит использовать composer init

Comment: Да, совершенно верно

Comment: _Я решил один из разделов сайта вынести на поддомен_ обычно такие задачи решаются с помощью nginx или apache, а не в пространстве имен php)))

Comment: Ну перепишите функцию autoload, чтобы она находила ваши файлы сайта с поддомена правильно. Тут можно посмотреть, как это вообще выглядит: https://gitlab.com/Zendden/micro-mvc-framework/-/blob/master/app/core/Autolaod.php